# Validating field uniqueness via Ajax call with appropriate message in Rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, jquery, unique

I am trying to do a Rails + AJAX call validation to check for the uniqueness of a field, by crawling the back end DB and return an appropriate message based on the result.

I am on Rails 3.0.11.

Is there a Ruby gem, JS plugin or jQuery plugin that I can make use of?

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a model validation just as you would in a regular page request, sending back the validation message via JSON in the controller?  For example, if you want to prevent a "contact" from saving without a unique email, in contact.rb add

```
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true
```

and in the create method of your controller, you could do something like the Rails scaffold generator would:

```
# POST /contacts
# POST /contacts.json
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.save
      format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @contact, status: :created, location: @contact }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Your javascript would then test for `status` and respond accordingly.

(Note: this is what the Rails 3.2 scaffold generator creates, 3.0 still did `format.xml` I think.  I don't think there's any major difference other than that change.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the client side validations Gem.

There is a good railscast on it 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations